# explode text file into array depend on comma

Tags: php, regex, reference

I'd like to convert my text.tx into array depend on only comma for example:

if I have this text:
[image]

so what I need to execute my array like that:

[image]

please check my code, my code not work well because it's depend on comma and newline:

```
<?php
$lines = file ("text.txt");
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $data[] = explode(',', $line);
}
?>
<pre>
    <?php
    print_r($data);
    ?>
</pre>
```

Comment: Not pictures! Edit your question and copy paste the text. Also, why is `like this` `like that` in your expected result, you need more than explode for that

Comment: `this` morphs into `that`.

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain what isn't working well with your current explode?

Answer (score -1):

```
$handle = fopen("text.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    $data = [];
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $data[] = explode(',', $line);
    }

    fclose($handle);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data); 
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
```